# Item template for dropdownlist in Asp.Net Mvc Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is it possible to define an Item template for such a dropdown definition, where `Model.ViewModel.Values` is a `SelectList`. The value of the is a simple oject like `{string Id, string Name}`. I would like to display `<B>Id</B> Name`

```
<select class="form-control" asp-for="ViewModel.Value" asp-items="Model.ViewModel.Values">
</select>
```

if not. What could you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `ViewBag`

In Controller

```
List<SelectListItem> select_list = new List<SelectListItem>();

var query = from li in YourObjectList
select new SelectListItem()
{
      Value = li.Id.ToString(),
    Text = "<B>"+li.Id.ToString()+"</B>"+li.Name.ToString(),
};
select_list = query.ToList();
ViewBag.list = select_list;
```

Then in the View

```
@Html.DropDownList("YourDataModel", ViewBag.list as List<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "form-control" })
```